# Can Pywinauto Recorder record web app elements?

Tags: pywinauto

Can the pywinauto recorder use to record browser based web apps elements/tags like hyperlinks, buttons, div, inputs, etc. If it is possible than can it be integrated in a work flow containing few work on web than following with desktop application. For example I I want to automate a process when involves:

1. Opening browser
2. Open mail website
3. Opening specific mail
4. Downloading excels files
5. Minimizing browser and opening download folder
6. Copying recentely downloaded files and pasting in desktop folder.
7. Opening a "xyz" software and inputing details from excel files to that software.

It would be helpful for my college project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pywinauto Recorder can do all these things!

- Here is [the code of the first tutorial of Pywinauto Recorder](https://github.com/beuaaa/pywinauto_recorder/blob/master/Tutorials/Tutorial_01/tutorial_01.py)
- Here is [the result of the recorded video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQiT5w4dzgE)

The video is generated using Pywinauto Recorder with the code in the first link. It may inspire you to do something similar.

Nevertheless, to automate an internet browser there are other solutions like Selenium which is specialized in the automation of internet browsers.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply and yes I know about selenium. It is very good for browsers. But I have a question. How to integrate `selenium` workflow followed by `pywinauto` workflow in a single record?